# GCC Win32 API Linking Issue with ComCtl32

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, comctl32

I can't get Comctl32.lib to link with my program using GCC (MinGW).

GCC Input:

```
gcc -o program.exe main.c images.o -lgdi32 -lcomctl32 -mwindows
```

GCC Output

```
main.c: In function 'WinMain':
main.c:120:2: error: unknown type name 'INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX'
main.c:124:9: error: request for member 'dwICC' in something not a structure or union
```

Related Code in main.c

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmd)
{
   Line 120: INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
   Line 124: icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
   InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);
}
```

Thank you for any help or information you can provide. I've been at this too long and just can't come up with an answer.

Comment: Don't you need defines like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx

Comment: I don't believe so. I have changed it to 0x0601 and added WINVER. It is just a linker issue I believe, nothing to do with defines.

Comment: Solved, this let me figure out the issue.

Comment: Good work. I knew it would be something along those lines.

Comment: A hint to those looking: might be obvious and evident (and not the problem in this case), but the order in which objects are listed on the command line is relevant; -lcomctl32 *must* follow main.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved the issue thanks to David H. I had to define

```
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0900
```

I was under the impression that commctrl.h was defining 0x0500 by default (0x0300 is required for my functions), but it appears it wasn't.

> If you do not define the _WIN32_IE macro in your project, it is automatically defined as 0x0500. - [MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298349(v=vs.85).aspx)